# Tooltips at right of the columns of an amcharts4 horizontal barchart

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I have an `amcharts 4` horizontal bar chart as in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stla/2v6w1fn7/14/). I want to have the *tooltips at the right of the columns, with the tooltip pointer touching the extremity of the column*.

I have tried

```
tooltip.adapter.add("dx", (x, target) => {
  return valueAxis.valueToPoint(target.dataItem.valueX).x;
})
```

but that does not provide the wanted result. I have also tried to play with `horizontalCenter`, `rotation`, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

```
    tooltip.dx = 0;
    tooltip.rotation = 180;
    tooltip.label.verticalCenter = "bottom";
    tooltip.label.rotation = 180;

    columnTemplate.adapter.add("tooltipX", (x, target) => {
      if (target.dataItem.valueX > 0) {
        return valueAxis.valueToPoint(target.dataItem.valueX + minValue).x;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
```

If the value is negative, then the tooltip is at the left of the column. This is also what I wanted.

Fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stla/2v6w1fn7/40/).